# como cambiar sonidos de MessageBox C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, messagebox

Mi duda es justo esa, es posible cambiar el sonido predeterminado que hace el MessageBox al ser despleagado? por que por ejemplo quiero que el que muestra un error haga un sonido diferente a los demas, es esto posible o hay que hacer un form como MessageBox?

Comment: Diría que ese sonido se configura a nivel de Sistema Operativo, en "Sonidos Predeterminados".

Comment: si necesitas cambiar esto vas a tener que crear tu propio MessageBox en un form, asi podras personalizarlo